# Can we redirect to another route with condition in destroy() in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-10

Scenario: A post has a delete button in all posts list view and the postShow view. So if the post is deleted from the list it will return back()->with('success', 'Some message') but if we delete it from the postShow view then redirect to the home.

(in short if the the post is deleted via show page then it redirects to home else redirect back)

```
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->delete();

    if(route('post.show', $post->slug)){
        return redirect()->route('home')->with(["message" => "Your Post has been deleted successfully");
    } else {
        return back()->with(["message" => "Your Post has been deleted successfully");
    }
}
```

This is the code but it is always redirecting to home.

Comment: You can try `if (request()->headers->get('referer') == route('post.show', $post->slug))` to check where the form was submitted from. Keep in mind this header is set by the browser so can be tampered by the client so don't use this without additional sanity checks

Comment: A simple solution is to send the destination on the call imagine url like so posts?redirectDestination=home. if ($request->get('redirectDestination') === 'home') { // redirect home}

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am using bootstrap modal form to have a alert before deletion of the post. so on modal submit I'm submitting a form. 
I've resolve the problem partially and after deletion from post.show page it is redirecting to home else returning back() now.
Just one issue message is not showing.

Comment: @mrhn I kinda followed your idea. I sent a hidden input value from postShow page and check if the request include that value or not. It is working as I expected but the issue now is: message is not coming up in alert.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the simplest way to approach this would be to include a query parameter when you are sending the request from the all posts list view.

From the all posts list view you could add the parameter `redirectTo` with the value `home`.

Then in the controller based on the `redirectTo` parameter you can implement your own redirection logic.

```
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->delete();
    $redirectTo = $request->get('redirectTo') ?? "";

    if($redirectTo == "home"){
        return redirect()->route('home')->with(["message" => "Your Post has been deleted successfully");
    } else {
        return back()->with(["message" => "Your Post has been deleted successfully");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`route('post.show', $post->slug)` will always evaluate as `true`, isn't it? Hence it is always redirecting to the home page.

---

Note that the below method is not hack proof, but the task at hand is too trivial to make it hack proof anyway.

In your routes, you can have the route for delete as below with additional parameter of `fromList`

```
Route::delete('/post/delete/{id}/{fromList}', ...)->name('post.delete');
```

In your **view** files, the delete route link would be,

**List page** - `route('post.delete',['id' => $yourID, 'fromList' => 1])`

**Show page** - `route('post.delete',['id' => $yourID, 'fromList' => 0])`

Then in your controller's delete method, you can check where to redirect based on the `fromList` flag.

```
<?php

public function delete($id, $fromList){
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $post->delete();

    if($fromList == '0'){
        return redirect()->route('home')->with(["message" => "Your Post has been deleted successfully"]);
    } 

    return back()->with(["message" => "Your Post has been deleted successfully"]);
}
```

Comment: I am using the bootstrap modal to make a confirm before deleting. The route for deletion is submitting a post request to the method. so the actual method is having $request parameter  which get the id of the post.

Comment: With a similar approach I've managed to redirect it back to the home. I've passed a hidden input variable checking that flag for post.show.
But it is not displaying the alert message as it works for back()

Comment: @YanikKumar If your route is placed as I did, you can have `$id` and `$fromList` as your2nd and 3rd parameters. The alert message should show up. Perhaps, you need to share the view blade code in your post where it doesn't show.

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided is not working as expected because the condition `if(route('post.show', $post->slug))` will always evaluate to true. This condition is checking if the route "post.show" with the post's slug exists, and it will exist as long as you have defined the "post.show" route in your routes file.

To achieve the desired behavior of redirecting to the home page if the post is deleted from the "postShow" view and redirecting back otherwise, you can modify your code like this:

```php
$post = Post::findOrFail($id);
$isDeletedFromShowPage = false; // Initialize a variable to track if deleted from show page

if (/* Add your condition to check if deleted from show page */) {
    // Delete logic here
    $isDeletedFromShowPage = true;
    $post->delete();
}

if ($isDeletedFromShowPage) {
    return redirect()->route('home')->with(["message" => "Your Post has been deleted successfully"]);
} else {
    return back()->with(["message" => "Your Post has been deleted successfully"]);
}
```

In the condition where you check if the post is deleted from the "postShow" view, you should add your logic to determine whether it was deleted from that specific view. If it was deleted from the show page, set the `$isDeletedFromShowPage` variable to true, and then use that variable to determine the redirect behavior.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy